# Integrate Payment Gateway with IONIC

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Don't mark question as duplicate or already asked. If know please answer.

I am trying to integrate payumoney payment gateway in my hybrid app. I went through some tutorials and finally reached to plugin cordovaInAppBrowser and using its events, loadstart, loadstop but not able to send and get parameters.Since last One Week I stucked and so finally posting here. Thanks, in advance

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: How to pass the parameters to page in ionic. As in website I have done it, but in ionic the same procedure is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I succeed in integrating the payment gateway in ionic. Its very easy, jsut follow the following steps,

1. add the cordovaInAppBrowser plugin and Inject the dependency.
2. make all the fields you get that to send to that Gateway with all validations.
3. now you needed some 3 files as success.php, failure.php and paymentfile.html.
4. $cordovaInAppBrowser.open("filename?"+params, '_blank',options)
5. make note that success and faliure php file are in server and access them through server
6. get the response in the php file than to controller, based on the response traverse the path and its done.

Most important you need to serialize the data while sending as its should be global and assign it to window object.
Also we have to use the cordovaInAppBrowser events loadstop() and all the stuff i had done in this event and later i call the close() function when its done.

Its Done.

Comment: Thank you @Nitin, for giving the hint to serialize the object , as which i was searching that.

Comment: can you explain it  with more detail

Comment: which params loadStop() have in callback? how to get know if success.php or failure.php opened?

Comment: @VivekSinha, its an event that gives the url / location, based on which we get the success / failure page. Try to print that event in console and you will able to know

Comment: @NitinAgarwal is you could share code example it will be a great help..

Comment: I also want the same payment method on ionic.please share some code please @NitinAgarwal

Comment: I was following this:

https://github.com/IonicU/payuhybridappintegration

But its not returning values back in app. Please help as you done it already, I am new in this..

Comment: response from paymoney. I am getting html data but if  I print values in app.console() its not printed. Please help

Comment: @SunilRawat, U r getting the response from pay u money like success page or failure page, with the data. Just you need to load the controller by checking the values like $location.url. IF success{//// code goes here} else {/..... code goes here}

Comment: function iabLoadStop(event) { 
    
    if (event.url.match("https://payu.herokuapp.com/success")) { 
      
        iabRef.executeScript({
            code: "document.body.innerHTML"
        }, function(values) {     
           
          
            var status = getValue(values[0], 'status');
            console.log(status);//Not print the value
            
            if(status == 'failure'){
                window.location = 'http://google.com';
            }            
            
        });
  
  iabRef.close();
  }
}
Above function not getting any response.

Comment: IAB is neither closing on sucess url nor fetching values to console log.If you have any code snipet please share it will be great help. If you relay done this.

Comment: @SunilRawat, I doesn't have any code snippet but i will help you. I am using cordova InAppBrowser, where the page renders. When the location is surl / furl i get the status, call the loadStop event in app and now the controllers get the data based on the url and flow goes on.

Comment: That is the my question, I am not able to get the data from the success response to redirect it to controller from my app. 
 
function iabLoadStop(event) { if (event.url.match("payu.herokuapp.com/success")) { iabRef.executeScript({ code: "document.body.innerHTML" }, function(values) { var status = getValue(values[0], 'status'); console.log(status);//Not print the value if(status == 'failure'){ window.location = 'google.com';; } }); iabRef.close(); } }

 if(status == 'failer'){
window.location = 'google.com'
not redirecting anymore or even, not geting values in this function.

Comment: @SunilRawat. We never send the data to the payment gateway. We only send the money/ amount with their merchant id,key what all they require. Later Based on the url you get the success page or failure page.

Comment: @SunilRawat, As you already have the data what the customer has send assign it to $rootScope and based on the location url prompt the message and show the data what he had send. As Stack was not allowing me to post whole comments so 2 messages.

Comment: @NitinAgarwal , can you please provide you email id?

Comment: I want to show you my code brother. I am struggling in this please help if you can..

Comment: on click payment button following function get called in my ionic . app.js:

function onDeviceReadyTest() {
    iabRef = window.open('payuBiz.html', '_blank', 'location=no');
}
//in payuBiz.html all mandetory paremeters set already.

Comment: in in this function:
function iabLoadStop(event) {
    if (event.url.match("https://payu.herokuapp.com/")) {
var c = getValue(values[0], 'unmappedstatus');
            console.log(b);//you can capture values from return SURL

}
Not getting rresponse values..

Comment: I have mailed you my code snipt please check. is that code correct which I am using. :

https://github.com/IonicU/payuhybridappintegration

Comment: @SunilRawat, have you done this payment gatway in ionic?

Comment: @SunilRawat Great. Did you the same procedure or tried something else...?

Comment: @SunilRawat can you please share code with me. rawat.hemant27@gmail.com

Comment: @NitinAgarwal i am stucking at same thing in ionic3 with amazon payment service . Can you please share some code what you did for inAppBrowser ?